# smarty post data from while/section loop

Tags: php, templates, loops, smarty

I have a smarty page that loops through a table in the database. For each row, I have a submit button. If I click the submit button it should only post back the data for that row. The problem is it posts back the very last row each time. It cant distinguish the difference per row. Any ideas?

Heres my code:

```
    <!--{section name=ct  loop=$data}-->
    <tr>
    <td><center><!--{$data[ct].id}--></center></td>
    <td><!--{$data[ct].name}--></td>
    <td><!--{$data[ct].cars}--></td>
    <td><!--{assign var=key value=$data[ct].id}-->       
    <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<!--{$key}-->">
    <a href="javascript:;" 
onclick="javascript:erase();return false;">DELETE</a>
    </tr>
    <!--{/section}-->
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: It loops through 10 rows in table. I want to delete lets say row 3. How do I select which row to delete? When its posts back to the server, I always get the last rows id.

Comment: How are you passing it to server i cant see that code here, is it through  `javascript:erase();` or it is just for confirm message ?

Comment: it is just an alert confirmation message.

Comment: on the server side I am just echoing $_POST['id']; and I alwayse see the wrong row displayed back.

Comment: What does your function `erase()` do ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple, input field with same name, it always overwrite the previous one, So you are always getting the value for last one.

Solution :

```
<a href="server_page.php?id={$key}" onclick="javascript:erase();">DELETE</a>
```

Get this id in your server page, using `$id= $_GET['id'];` and do delete in your database.